# ggarrange plot all plots in a list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have lots of plot that I want to put them on one page, `ggarrange` does a good work on this, however, it seems like I have to put each of those plots in the list in which  they are stored as input of this `ggarrange` function, other than put the list as input directly, see following for details:

A naive example:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ cyl, ncol=2, scales = "free") +
  guides(colour="none") +
  theme()
plot_list = list(p1,p2)
```

What I can do for now:

```
ggarrange(p1,p2, widths = c(2,1), labels = c("a", "b"))
```

What I really want but failed to do:

```
ggarrange(plot_list, widths = c(2,1), labels = c("a", "b"))
```

Anyone know how? this could save a lot of time if the number of plots is large and may change from time to time.
The sample is not mine, copied from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/egg/versions/0.4.0/topics/ggarrange).

**======= EDIT ========**

According to the excellent answers below, there are at least two options available:

1. See the accepted answer,
2. Which is come from a deleted answer with little modification by me
   `do.call(ggarrange, c(plot_list[1:2], widths = c(2, 1), labels = c("a", "b")))`
   To pass argument to function `ggarrange`, `c()` worked for me but `as.list()` did not.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out the help file for `?ggarrange`. It has a `plotlist=` parameter. Just pass your list there.

```
ggarrange(plotlist=plot_list, widths = c(2,1), labels = c("a", "b"))
```

Comment: This works indeed. The problem is that I checked the documentation at the wrong place (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/egg/versions/0.4.0/topics/ggarrange), which presents argument `plots = list(...)` rather than `plotlist = NULL` from `?ggarrange`. Remind me again to always be aware of function versions.

Comment: It does appear that there are two different packages with a `ggarrange` function. This works specifically for the `ggpubr` package. The link you provided is for the `egg` package. I guess that's why it's important to be clear about what packages you are using when you are calling non-base R functions.

Comment: Yes, it indeed is true, you take me one more step further, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
egg::ggarrange(plots = plot_list, widths = c(2,1), labels = c("a", "b"))
```

Comment: A blob of code is not an answer. Explain why you think this answers the question.