# ggarrange, combine multiple plots with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a list of plots (15 in total).
[image]

I want to arrange them in a single page with a 3x5 matrix
I used ggarrange with two plots
[image]

Now i want to do it with all the plots

```
Moran_plot_eu_std <-ggarrange(plots=plotlist,
                              common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom",
                              ncol = 3, nrow = 5)
```

But it doesn't work or send back error message

Comment: You've assigned the combined plot to an object.  What happens if you remove the assignment?  Or just type `Moran_plot_eu_std`?

Comment: Please provide the error message

Comment: I've just red the online doc.  (Always a good thing to do.)  You need `plotlist=plotlist`, not `plots=plotlist`.  (And then `Moran_plot_eu_std` if you're saving to an object.)

Comment: @Limey It's strange because I have checked here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/egg/versions/0.4.0/topics/ggarrange
But your modification works great (be careful to set enough width/height in output settings ! )
I also find solution on another stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048776/ggarrange-plot-all-plots-in-a-list
wwith following command that works also great `do.call(ggarrange, c(plot_list[1:2], widths = c(2, 1), labels = c("a", "b"))).`